# Is the order of bosses fixed?

Tags: rogue-legacy

I've seen a lot of people referring to "1st boss", "2nd boss", etc. As far as I can tell, that's more common than calling them by their name, and most people seem to understand it. As I haven't really had time to play it all that successfully, I've yet to meet a boss, too.

Is there a fixed order, or some kind of suggested order in which one should pursue the bosses? Can I influence which boss I'm fighting next?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically, you can fight the bosses in any order that you want.  There's nothing in the game that will prevent you from doing so.  There's only a single boss room in each area, so you know who you'll be fighting before you try.  ie. Khidir is always the Castle boss.

The generally accepted difficulty level is ordered as:

- Castle
- Forest
- Tower
- Dungeon

And the map in the first room supports that, as do the journal entries.  If you're going for easiest to hardest, that's probably the best way to go about it.

Comment: Mhhh.. could be that I remember incorrectly, but wasn't the journal order castle - tower - forest - dungeon?

Comment: @5pike Nope.  Forest definitely comes before tower.  Check the map in the first room.

Comment: And the journal entry mentioned the forest immediately following the Castle. I remember that, as I only just found that entry yesterday. =P